The RFID Reader and Rfid Tags intrgration with React Native
Currently, I am working on integration with Rfid reader, and Rfid Tag with our devices in React Native.
My projects description is:
Connect RFID Reader to our device.

When a RFID Tag comes in range of RFID reader then read the RFID  Tag data and show it on our devices.

also in our ui have three button like start stop reset when we clicked on start button it check firstly any RFID Tag is range of RFID  reader then it scan show data



import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Modal,
  FlatList,
  SafeAreaView,
  PermissionsAndroid,
  NativeModules,
  NativeEventEmitter,
  useColorScheme,
  StyleSheet,
  Platform,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';
import BleManager from 'react-native-ble-manager';
import {Colors} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import {Buffer} from 'buffer';
import encodeUtf8 from 'encode-utf8';

const BleManagerModule = NativeModules.BleManager;
const BleManagerEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(BleManagerModule);

const BleConnectDevice = () => {
  const [isScanning, setIsScanning] = useState(false);
  const [devices, setDevices] = useState([]);
  const [connectedDevices, setConnectedDevices] = useState([]);
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [readData, setReadData] = useState('');
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  const characteristic = 'ffe1';
  const service = 'ffe0';

  useEffect(() => {
    BleManager.enableBluetooth()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Bluetooth is turned on!');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Bluetooth enable error:', error);
      });

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      requestPermissions();
    }
  }, []);

  const requestPermissions = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE,
      ]);

      if (
        granted['android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'] ===
          PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED &&
        granted['android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN'] ===
          PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED &&
        granted['android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT'] ===
          PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED &&
        granted['android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE'] ===
          PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED
      ) {
        console.log('All permissions granted');
      } else {
        console.log('Permissions denied');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn('Permission request error:', err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    BleManager.start({showAlert: false}).then(() => {
      console.log('BleManager initialized');
    });

    const handleDiscoverPeripheral = peripheral => {
      if (!peripheral.name) {
        peripheral.name = 'NO NAME';
      }
      setDevices(prevDevices => {
        const deviceExists = prevDevices.find(
          device => device.id === peripheral.id,
        );
        if (deviceExists) {
          return prevDevices;
        } else {
          return [...prevDevices, peripheral];
        }
      });
    };

    BleManagerEmitter.addListener(
      'BleManagerDiscoverPeripheral',
      handleDiscoverPeripheral,
    );

    return () => {
      BleManagerEmitter.removeListener(
        'BleManagerDiscoverPeripheral',
        handleDiscoverPeripheral,
      );
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const stopListener = BleManagerEmitter.addListener(
      'BleManagerStopScan',
      () => {
        setIsScanning(false);
        console.log('Scan is stopped');
      },
    );

    return () => {
      stopListener.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  const startScan = () => {
    if (!isScanning) {
      BleManager.scan([], 5, true)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Scanning...');
          setIsScanning(true);
          setModalVisible(true);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Scan error:', error);
        });
    }
  };

  const stopScan = () => {
    if (isScanning) {
      BleManager.stopScan()
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Stopped scanning');
          setIsScanning(false);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Stop scan error:', error);
        });
    }
  };

  const resetScan = () => {
    setDevices([]);
    setConnectedDevices([]);
    setReadData('');
    console.log('Reset complete');
  };

  const connectToDevice = device => {
    BleManager.connect(device.id)
      .then(() => {
        return BleManager.retrieveServices(device.id);
      })
      .then(peripheralInfo => {
        console.log('Services and characteristics:', peripheralInfo);
        setModalVisible(false);
        setConnectedDevices(prevDevices => [...prevDevices, device]);
      })
      .then(() => {
        return BleManager.startNotification(device.id, service, characteristic);
      })

      .then(() => {
        BleManagerEmitter.addListener(
          'BleManagerDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic',
          handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic,
        );
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error connecting to device:', error);
      });
  };

  const handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic = data => {
    console.log('Received data from characteristic', data);
    const buffer = Buffer.from(data.value);
    const sensorData = buffer.toString('ascii');
    console.log('Received data:', sensorData);
    setReadData(sensorData);
    Alert.alert('Received data: ' + sensorData);
  };

  const disconnectFromDevice = device => {
    BleManager.disconnect(device.id)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Disconnected from ' + device.name);
        setConnectedDevices(prevDevices =>
          prevDevices.filter(d => d.id !== device.id),
        );
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Disconnection error', error);
      });
  };

  const readDataFromDevice = (deviceId, serviceUUID, characteristicUUID) => {
    BleManager.startNotification(deviceId, serviceUUID, characteristicUUID);
    BleManager.read(deviceId, serviceUUID, characteristicUUID)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Started notifications.');
      })
      .then(readData => {
        console.log(readData, 'readdddd');
        // const buffer = Buffer.from(readData);
        // console.log(buffer, 'bufferrr');
        // const sensorData = buffer.toString('ascii');
        // console.log(sensorData, 'sensorrr');
        // setReadData(sensorData);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Notification error:', error);
      });
    BleManager.addListener(
      'BleManagerDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic',
      handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic,
      // data => {
      //   console.log('Received2333 data:', decodeData(data.value));
      //   // Update UI with received data
      // },
    );
  };
  const decodeData = encodedData => {
    // Convert received data to its original format
    return encodedData;
  };

  const sendCom = async peripheral => {
    const data = encodeUtf8('1'); // convert data to bytes

    BleManager.retrieveServices(peripheral)
      .then(() => {
        BleManager.startNotification(peripheral, service, characteristic);
      })
      .then(() => {
        BleManager.writeWithoutResponse(
          peripheral.id,
          service,
          characteristic,
          data,
        );
        console.log(`Sent: ${data}`);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(`Error writing ${characteristic}: ${error}`);
      });
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>React Native BLE Manager</Text>

        <View style={styles.deviceList}>
          {connectedDevices.length > 0 ? (
            connectedDevices.map(device => (
              <View key={device.id} style={styles.connectedDevice}>
                <View>
                  <Text style={styles.deviceName}>{device.name}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.deviceId}>{device.id}</Text>
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  activeOpacity={0.5}
                  onPress={() => disconnectFromDevice(device)}
                  style={styles.disconnectButton}>
                  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Disconnect</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            ))
          ) : (
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.5}
              onPress={startScan}
              style={styles.scanButton}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Scan</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        </View>

        {connectedDevices.length > 0 && (
          <View style={styles.buttonWrap}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.5}
              onPress={readDataFromDevice(
                connectedDevices[0]?.id,
                '0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb',
                '0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb',
              )}
              style={[styles.resetButton, {backgroundColor: '#0a84ff'}]}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Start</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.5}
              onPress={stopScan}
              style={styles.stopButton}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Stop</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.5}
              onPress={resetScan}
              style={styles.resetButton}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Reset</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )}

        <Modal visible={modalVisible} animationType="slide">
          <SafeAreaView style={styles.modalContainer}>
            <FlatList
              data={devices}
              renderItem={({item}) => (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.deviceContainer}
                  onPress={() => connectToDevice(item)}>
                  <Text style={styles.deviceName}>{item.name}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.deviceId}>{item.id}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.5}
              onPress={() => setModalVisible(false)}
              style={styles.scanButton}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Close</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </SafeAreaView>
        </Modal>
        <View style={styles.dataContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.dataText}>Received Data:</Text>
          <Text style={styles.dataText}>{readData}</Text>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 24,
    backgroundColor: Colors.lighter,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: Colors.black,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginBottom: 24,
  },
  deviceList: {
    marginBottom: 24,
  },
  connectedDevice: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 16,
    backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
    borderRadius: 8,
    marginBottom: 16,
  },
  deviceContainer: {
    padding: 16,
    backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
    borderRadius: 8,
    marginBottom: 16,
  },
  deviceName: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: Colors.black,
  },
  deviceId: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: Colors.dark,
  },
  scanButton: {
    padding: 16,
    backgroundColor: '#007aff',
    borderRadius: 8,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  stopButton: {
    padding: 16,
    backgroundColor: '#ff3b30',
    borderRadius: 8,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  resetButton: {
    padding: 16,
    backgroundColor: '#ffcc00',
    borderRadius: 8,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontWeight: '600',
  },
  buttonWrap: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    marginBottom: 24,
  },
  disconnectButton: {
    padding: 8,
    backgroundColor: '#ff3b30',
    borderRadius: 8,
  },
  modalContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 24,
    backgroundColor: Colors.lighter,
  },
  dataContainer: {
    marginTop: 16,
    padding: 16,
    backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
    borderRadius: 8,
  },
  dataText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: Colors.black,
  },
});

export default BleConnectDevice;

When I click on the start button, it integrates with the RFID reader, and if a tag is present, it gives data.
